# Thermal Conductivity of Calcium Carbonate?

Tags: bond, energy, metal

Is Calcium Carbonate (Group 1 and 2) able to conduct heat more than other carbonate (Transition metal) allowing for them to be decomposed faster. The reason I am asking this question is because my experimental result from burning carbonates through a test tube and finding the exact time it starts to bubble (start of decomposition) shows that these metal carbonates decompose way faster than other metals. (Results are below)

(Substance Trial 1 (s),Trial 2 (s),Trial 3 (s),Trial 4 (s))
Zinc Carbonate, 30.70 s, 26.35 s, 25.24 s, 25.17 s
Nickel Carbonate, 30.65 s, 20.25 s, 20.27 s, 20.31 s
Lead Carbonate, 16.54 s, 17.66 s, 16.58 s, 16.73 s
Magnesium Carbonate, 10.06 s, 9.84 s, 10.19 s, 9.92 s
Calcium Carbonate, 7.66 s, 7.43 s, 7.57 s, 7.98 s

Answer (score 1):

You have not measured thermal conductivity, you measured a rate of reaction under a rather poorly defined set of conditions.

If I was going to deal with this problem then I would first want to do some thermal gravimetric anaylsis on the carbonates to determine how hot I have to heat them to decompose them. I would also want to use an experiment similar to Lee's disk to get the thermal conductivtiy. Years ago I was shown this experiment being used on thin disks of uranium dioxide nuclear fuel.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234935832_Thermal_conductivity_of_uranium_dioxide_up_to_2900_K_from_simultaneous_measurement_of_the_heat_capacity_and_thermal_diffusivity
http://www.phox.at/upload/Laser%20Flash%20Method%20to%20Determine%20Thermal%20Conductivity.pdf
https://www.pragolab.cz/documents/Linseis_Laser_Flash_Thermal_Conductivity.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the response and I apologize for just replying to this. Sadly I do not have access to these apparatus as i am confined to using standard school laboratory apparatus . Can you point out exactly why these are poorly defined sets of conditions for me? I am still a high school student as such my knowledge is still very limited

Comment: Also my research/school project is trying to assess which of these carbonates decompose faster to show that they follow the trend of the reactivity series whereby less reactive metal decompose faster due to the weaker polarization, not really thermal conductivity. The reason why I am asking thermal conductivity is because I am confused as to why Group 1 and 2 metal decompose faster than the least reactive metals (Pb)